# How to delete a file, rename another file to the deleted filename in Git

Tags: git

My team has been working on a game that was 16 bits originally. We have since simplified to 10 bits. My understanding of ideal Git strategy would be to create a branch `10Bit`, and change the code to 10 bits without altering the filenames; however, my teammate made copies of several files, with `10Bit` appended to the filename, without deleting the old file. This was several commits ago, and now our filesystem looks like this:

```
Master.sv    # <--Old 16-bit code, not used in 10-bit
Master10Bit.sv
Master_Constraints.xdc # <-- same
Master_Constraints10Bit.xdc
Slave.sv    #    <-- same
Slave10Bit.sv
```

We want to get back to the original names, without the `10Bit` part. But if I do

```
git rm Master.sv
git mv Master10Bit.sv Master.sv
```

git doesn't see this as a simple file rename. Instead, `git status` or a `git diff` shows that `Master10Bit.sv` was deleted, and `Master.sv` was changed significantly. This *isn't* what happened, though; a `git diff` should show that `Master.sv` was deleted, and that `Master10Bit.sv` was renamed to `Master.sv`.

Likewise for all the other files.

What's a good way to go about this change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must remove Master.sv, commit changes and finaly rename Master10Bit.sv to Master.sv.

```
git rm Master.sv
git commit -m "Remove old files"
git mv Master10Bit.sv Master.sv
git commit -m "Rename files"
```

Comment: For something like this, because it's done in two steps, should I label in the commit message that it is part of a multi-part renaming? Eg. `Part 1/2`

Comment: @AlexG: The two separate commits aren't actually *required*, but it is a good idea as it makes things clearer, when someone who is not aware of this history comes back to figure out what happened, when, and why. Likewise, marking the two commits "part 1 of 2" and "part 2 of 2" isn't actually *required*, but it is a good idea...